# Java MongoClient - `NoClassDefFoundException` when calling `aggregate` on a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using the mongodb driver version 3.10.1 for my project and I am facing the following error. I have the following query:

```
mongodbclient.getDatabase("test").getCollection("testColl")
                .aggregate(Arrays.asList(Filters.eq("_id","theID")));
```

This query throws a execption saying:

`NoClassDefFound for com/mongodb/client/AggregationLevel`

The same query on the mongoshell against the database returns the correct result. Even if I am passing a empty list into the aggregate I get the same exception. Is this a error in the mongodb driver or do I miss anything here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the default dependency for mongodb provided by mongodb:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Does not contain the needed dependency for core mongodb:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and BSON:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding them, the `aggregate` method is working.
Sad, but true.